# Python for-loop look-ahead

Tags: python

I have a python for loop, in which I need to look ahead one item to see if an action needs to be performed before processing.

```
for line in file:
    if the start of the next line == "0":
        perform pre-processing
        ...
    continue with normal processing
    ...
```

Is there any easy way to do this in python?
My current approach is to buffer the file to an array, however this is not ideal as the file is rather large.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can get any iterable to prefetch next item with this recipe:

```
from itertools import tee, islice, izip_longest
def get_next(some_iterable, window=1):
    items, nexts = tee(some_iterable, 2)
    nexts = islice(nexts, window, None)
    return izip_longest(items, nexts)
```

Example usage:

```
for line, next_line in get_next(myfile):
    if next_line and next_line.startswith("0"):
        ... do stuff
```

The code allows you to pass the `window` parameter as a larger value, if you want to look 2 or more lines ahead.

Comment: does this cause it to read twice from the file, or does it buffer the line somehow?

Comment: It reads only once. See `teedataobject_getitem` in [`itertoolsmodule.c`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release27-maint/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c)

Comment: Your `get_next` is in the itertools receipes as [`pairwise`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)

Comment: Using `izip_longest` and then using `next_line` (is not None) are not needed in this case. If you revert `izip_longest` to `izip` and instead of using `islice` simply calling `next` on the `nexts` iterator, you get `pairwise`. And then I can retire my answer below.

Comment: @Muhammad Alkarouri: What makes you think your solution is better? What's wrong with my approach (using `izip_longest` and `islice`)?

Comment: @nosklo: It is not my approach. It is the `pairwise` function from itertools help as THC4k noted. `islice`'s only problem is being overkill for this. `izip_longest` and `izip` are different, you use the longest variation when you need the last pair having `None`, which is the exact opposite to what you are doing as you are checking to exclude the `None`. My main answer is to draw attention to the itertools recipes. However, if you think this is an issue to argue about do whatever you like. I am probably better off hanging to my 20 points rather than deleting the almost duplicate answer anyway.

Comment: @Muhamad Alkarouri: No, I'm just wondering **what** is better exactly about it. What's wrong with using `islice`? How exactly is it "overkill"?

Comment: @nosklo: Just to answer the technical part, to me `next(b, None)` seems much simpler and more direct than `nexts = islice(nexts, 1, None)`.

Comment: @Muhammad Alkarouri: However `islice` doesn't consume the iterable beforehand (as it could have side effects), and easily allows changing the `1` to something else to create a larger window, while you'd have to repeat `next` many times to get the same effect

Comment: I have added that info to the answer

Comment: @nosklo: You seem to have misunderstood the concept of a window, and I did mention that it is not trivial. A sliding window of size 5 should get you the current line _and the four lines_ before it. See the function I linked to. Another example is [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/lib/itertools-example.html), appropriately called `window`. Your function gives you two lines regardless of the window parameter.

Comment: @nosklo Please specify that your function is NOT the same as itertools.pairwise. Yours is much more useful for iterating over a sequence and process one element at a time while ensuring that all have been processed exactly once.

Answer (score 12):

Along the lines of nosklo's answer, I tend to use the following pattern:

The function `pairwise` from the excellent [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) is ideal for this:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Using it in your code gets us:

```
for line, next_line in pairwise(file):
    if next_line.startswith("0"):
        pass #perform pre-processing
        #...
    pass #continue with normal processing
```

Generally, for this type of processing (lookahead in the iterable), I tend to use a [window function](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-May/065304.html). Pairwise is a special case of a window of size 2.

Comment: What makes you think your solution is better? What's wrong with my approach (using `izip_longest` and `islice`)? My solution allows a bigger window more easily.

Comment: @nosklo: Try it. I am sure that you can do better than my link because I was just explaining the concept. I can do better as well. Note that it is not as trivial as you think. I am not sure what I did to tick you off, but I was hoping that we can get the best single answer for SO. If you edit yours to get there, I will be more than happy.

Comment: I have tried your code and I can't see what's better about it. I just see it being equivalent, at best. Mine is easier to extend to a window, though

Comment: `izip()` no longer works for py3. Use `zip()` instead.

Comment: One should note that when `len(iterable) == 1`, `pairwise`  will return an empty list.

Comment: @colelemonz: interesting. That is a difference from the accepted answer, and I wonder which is more useful for the original question. [pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) as defined here is an official Python function from 3.10.

Comment: @MuhammadAlkarouri I guess I should have read the docs closer because it states it right there "It will be empty if the input iterable has fewer than two values."

Answer (score 10):

You can have a `prev_line` where you store previous line and process that whenever you read a line only given your condition.

Something like:

```
prev_line = None
for line in file:
    if prev_line is not None and the start of the next line == "0":
        perform pre-processing on prev_line
        ...
    continue with normal processing
    ...
    prev_line = line
```

You may need to do additional processing for the last line if necessary, depending on your logic.

Answer (score 4):

This should work too. I always prefer calling `next` over setting `something = None` for the first round.

```
prev_line = next(the_file)
for current_line in the_file:
    if current_line.startswith('0'):
        do_stuff( prev_line )
    # continue with normal processing
    # ...
    prev_line = current_line
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to buffer one line.

```
for line in file:
  if (prevLine is not None):
    //test line as look ahead and then act on prevLine
  prevLine = line
```

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier than all that...

```
lines = len(file)
for i in range(0,lines):
    current_line = file[i]
    if i < lines - 1:
        next_line = file[i + 1]
    else:
        next_line = None

    do_your_work(current_line,next_line)
```

Answer (score 1):

`more_itertools` has several [lookahead tools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#lookahead).  Here we will demonstrate some tools and a abstracted function for processing lines of a file.  Given:

```
f = """\
A
B
C
0
D\
"""
lines = f.splitlines()
```

Code

```
import more_itertools as mit


def iter_lookahead(iterable, pred):
    # Option 1
    p = mit.peekable(iterable)
    try:
        while True:
            line = next(p)
            next_line = p.peek()
            if pred(next_line):
                # Do something
                pass
            else:
                print(line)
    except StopIteration:
        return


pred = lambda x: x.startswith("0")
iter_lookahead(lines, pred)
```

Output

```
A
B
0
```

---

Here are other options using the same library that include `pairwise` and `windowed` tools mentioned by @Muhammad Alkarouri.

```
# Option 2
for line, next_line in mit.pairwise(lines):
    if pred(next_line):            
        # Do something
        pass
    else:
        print(line)

# Option 3
for line, next_line in mit.windowed(lines, 2):
    if pred(next_line):            
        # Do something
        pass
    else:
        print(line)
```

The latter options can be run independently or substitute the logic in the prior function.