# Look ahead without itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I am looking for a way to look at the next line in a text file when the first characters are the letters are only A,G,C,U or N. I created a dict. of all possibilities in which I can look. I have tried itertools, but to no avail and I have heard that the itertools would keep everything in memory which would be most unproductive since my files are rather large(>10GB sometimes). I would really appreciate help, I have wandered here for days looking for an answer. I was thinking or trying regex, but I do not know how to. I really want to find the most productive way for big files. Here is my (pitiful) attempt.

I have taken part of an answer found on : [Python for-loop look-ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197805/python-for-loop-look-ahead)

```
f2 = open(path to file)
from itertools import tee
from itertools import permutations

def pairwise(iter):
   "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iter)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

p = permutations(['A','G','U','C','N'])
for per in p:
    per = ''.join(per)
    dic={'a':[]}
    dic['a'].append(per)

for line, next_line in pairwise(f2):


    if line in dic['a']:

        letter= next_line.split()
        unilist.append('%s' %next_line)
        print (unilist)
```

It appears the problem lies in the: for line, next_line in pairwise(f2)
I would be truly grateful for every tip and advice.

Edit: I meant the characters in the line and not the ones in the next_line.

Comment: Instead of trying to look ahead, look behind instead. Keep 2 lines in memory.

Comment: And the `pairwise()` method is a standard [`itertools` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

Comment: @Martijn Thanks again, you are always very helpful. Hopefully one day I can give back the way you do...

Comment: What is `f2`? It is not defined in your snippet of code.

Comment: @the wolf sorry I forgot to copy that part. It is edited now...

Comment: Why are you rebuilding `dic` for each permutation? In the end you only keep the last permutation. You probably want to define `dic = {'a': []}` **once**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I put the print statement to verify that with the wrong indent... Thanks I am right on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems with your code:

- You discard `dic` each permutation loop iteration and re-create it from scratch. Build it once:

  ```
  dic={'a':[''.join(per) for per in permutations('AGUCN')]}
  ```

  but for fast membership tests (`if something in sequence`), use a `set` instead:

  ```
  dic={'a': set(''.join(per) for per in permutations('AGUCN'))}
  ```

  Note that it is not clear why you need a dictionary with one key; a simple variable would do fine here.
- You read a file but don't strip the newlines from the lines. With a newline, your `if line in dic['a']` test will never return True because the code that generates the

Just treat the file as an iterable, call `next()` on it to get the next line:

```
from itertools import permutations

patterns = set(''.join(per) for per in permutations('AGUCN'))
unilist = []

for line in f2:
    if line.strip() in patterns:
        unilist.append(next(f2).strip())
```

or even:

```
from itertools import permutations

patterns = set(''.join(per) for per in permutations('AGUCN'))
unilist = [next(f2).strip() for line in f2 if line.strip() in patterns]
```

You are not really looking ahead. You are looking behind; if the previous line matched a condition, the next line is appended.

Answer (score 1):

"itertools is evil" is a completly unbased statement - on the contrary, itertools provide a set of *different* tools to deal with iterables,

In this case, you have to use `itertools.tee` - and no, it won't keep all your items in memory